# How to get data of dynamic columns from a Table

Tags: sql, dynamic, multiple-columns

I have an application where users select some column names based on their requirement. I have to get the values of only these columns from a table in the database. I looked [here](https://nothingtocode.wordpress.com/2015/02/06/hello-world/) and it is what I am looking for. I have two questions:

1. In the post they are adding columns and data to the DataTables from the code. How do I get this value from database?
2. In the post the author is using DataTables. I was asked to look if I can do the same without using them. Is there any other way of doing this? Tell me if I need to clarify anything else.

Comment: Please mention. What have you tried ?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select a list of columns of your table, So use this query (that works in some databases):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName'
ORDER BY  ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

---

When you want to have a SQL string with a dynamic set of column names I suggest you to set your SQL string at run-time based on user inputs or if you use a database like SQL Server; you can also use dynamic SQL (with `EXEC` command). Something like this:

```
foreach(var column in columns)
    if (column.IsSelectedByUser)
        strColumns += column.Name;

strSql = 'SELECT ' + strColumns + ' FROM yourTableName';
```

Comment: List<object> columns = new List<object>();
columns.Add("FirstName");
columns.Add("LastName"); then i have to pass these columns to select query. every time the list will change.

Comment: @Mounika As you tagged your question with `sql` to get list of columns, then I answer it with a SQL that give you column names- Now if you have another question I suggest you to ask a new question ;).